# How to organize better the controllers in symfony framework?

Tags: php, symfony, controller, code-organization

I have a lot of controllers I want to know ways to organize them better

Comment: I guess you have to be a little bit more specific if you want usefull answers.

Comment: I wanna know what is the best practice to organize concrete controllers and abstracts controllers in the symfony, so imagine that there are many controllers...

for example, is a best practice create subfolder in the controller folder to separate controllers?

Comment: Most likely what you describe means that the Symfony2 framework is not a fitting framework to organize all your controllers code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be very much common behavior between your controllers.  If you do have duplicate code or common behavior, then it should probably be refactored out to a service.  Thin controllers, fat models & services.

Knp University has a really good (and free) screencast on the topic:

http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/question-answer-day/model-organization